Is the imperative a grammatical tense?
Here I have read the following sentence:

Write it, along with the rest of your message, in the imperative tense:

Up until now I always thought that imperative is not a grammatical tense but a grammatical mood and therefore it is not correct to say "imperative tense".
Is this correct or not?

Try wikipedia

The author is not a grammarian nor a linguist, and the last time they studied English grammar, if ever, was probably in High School. It's a forgivable “error”. P.S you have a misspelling (or a typo) in the title.

It's neither a mood nor a tense, but a clause type.

@fev Dictionaries are not particularly reliable sources for grammatical concepts. This clearly shouldn't have been closed; the "dictionary" close reason is for questions that just ask what a word means, not for questions about grammar.

@fev No, not correct. It's not a mood type. Mood is mostly marked in English by modal auxiliaries.

Types of sentences: declarative, negative, interrogative and imperative moods. This is basic stuff, really.

No: the main clause types are declarative, interrogative, exclamative and imperative. Negative clauses are a sub-type of one of the main types. None of them are moods. They are clause types. Mood in today's English is marked by modal auxiliaries

@BillJ I forgot exclamative, sure but I said sentence, didn't? Some sentences only have a main clause.

The major clause types are those that correspond with the speech acts: The default correlation is: declarative (for making a statement), interrogative (for asking a question), exclamative (for making an exclamatory statement), and imperative (for issuing a directive).

It's not an imperative "tense" per se. It's more of an imperative mood/mode or context. While the attached Grammarly link discusses this, based on the definition of imperative, an easy way to think of it is that imperative statements create a relationship/context between the speaker and the listener where a response is expected. The imperative statement is a request to act or expression of expectation for action or result, e.g., such as a response to the statement. That statement is imperative as it is important for or related to what is to follow. It creates a situation or context of expectation from the participants. The imperative statement sets the stage for what's next.
Example: "Please remember to pick me up from the airport at 9:00 AM."
Note, the stage is set for a response, action, agreement, etc., to follow. The statement is needed, important, related to what follows.
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/imperative-sentences/

The imperative is a clause type. The other major clause types are Declarative, Interrogative and Exclamative.

@BillJ But the imperative is also a mood (Wikipedia). It might be helpful to specify that mood relates to the verb, which helps form an imperative clause.

I wouldn’t go along with all that you say. Inflectional mood, as in the contrast between indicative, subjunctive and imperative, exists in languages such as Latin, French and German. As far as English is concerned, historical change has more or less eliminated mood from the inflectional system, with irrealis mood confined to 1st/3rd person singular were. In other words, the main mood system is analytic rather than inflectional, marked by the presence of modal auxiliaries.
